# How logstash process field for ES date_range type?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Here is the mapping of target Elasticsearch index:

```
"mappings": {
"_doc": {
    "properties": {
        "start_time": {
            "format": "epoch_millis",
            "type": "date"
        },
    "channel": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "end_time": {
        "format": "epoch_millis",
        "type": "date"
    },
    "range_time": {
        "format": "epoch_millis",
        "type": "date_range"
    }
    }
}
}
```

And here is my related logstash config file:

```
filter {
mutate {
    split => ["message", "|"]
    add_field => {
        "start_time" => "%{[message][1]}"
        "end_time" => "%{[message][2]}"
        "channel" => "%{[message][5]}"
        **"range_time" => [
             "%{[message][1]}",
             "%{[message][2]}"
        ]**
        }
    remove_field => "message"
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost" ]
        index => "test_live"
    }
}
```

My question is how to write the "range_time" => part ([mutate][add_field][range_time]) for shipping date_range type data to ES.
In the console, I got the output like this:

```
{
"@timestamp" => 2021-04-19T01:46:40.617Z,
"start_time" => "20210401001401",
"end_time" => "20210401001408",
"range_time" => [
    [0] "20210401001401",
    [1] "20210401001408"
],
"host" => "localhost.localdomain",
"channel" => "SCTV-2",
"path" => "/**/",
"@version" => "1"
```

}

But the output can't write data to index correctly.
How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `date_range` field contains two fields named `gte` and `lte`.

So you simply need to do it like this:

```
add_field => {
  ...
  "[range_time][gte]" => "%{[message][1]}"
  "[range_time][lte]" => "%{[message][2]}"
}
```

Comment: Already successfully shipped data. Thank you !

Comment: I got one more question about the date_range field.  I think kibana can not recognize ES date_range type, I can not find the field in kibana dashboard and discovery. Any idea about this situation?

Comment: That's correct, this is not supported yet: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/33762

Comment: I would say. Really thanks for answering  my questions and sharing your knowledge to me.  Have a niceeeeee day.

Comment: Could you take a look about my new question when you are free? Thanks.